# Entity framework object not returning over WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, entity-framework, repository

I am using Entity Framework code first to create an object graph of linked objects and manipulate them in a web service, which is all hooked up fine. The problem I have is when I try and return the parent object across WCF. It is a User object with a number of child related entities.

The odd thing is if I deep clone the user object (my own implementation which creates a new User object with identical properties at all levels) and return the CLONED object, it works fine. It only doesnt work when I try to return the Object Entity returned by the EF.

The code which returns the object is

```
 var user = _userRepository.GetUser(userId);
 return user;
```

The IUserDataRepository is created via the Unity DI factory by a bootstrapped config that attaches to the factory in the Service Startup. The Context is also injected as a constructor dependency to the repository, wrapped in an IUnitOfWork object I have created. In the repository you have

```
public class UserDataRepository : IUserDataRepository
{
     public UserDataRepository(IUnitOfWork work)
        {
            this.Work = work;
        }

     private IUnitOfWork Work { get; set; }

     public DbUser GetUser(int id)
     {
        return UnitOfWork.Context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == id);
     }
}
```

When I try and return the loaded DbUser object, I get a 400 error, System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException (Bad Request)

However if I clone the object to a new DbUser object I create myself, that returns fine.

The only thing I can think of is EF still has some hooks into the DbUser object and won't let you pass that object back, whereas an identical object created manually is fine as it doesn't have the EF hooks in.

I have tried turning lazy loading off at a context level for all entities but still no joy.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What does the cloning code that works look like?

Comment: It's a very primitive static class method. It just manually creates a new DbUser object, populating each of the properties one by one by hand from the original object

Comment: Then what does your User class look like? Are any of the properties reference types whose values are stored as entities in other tables?

Comment: Yes, there are a number of primitive properties but also a lot of other linked entities which are each stored in other tables. ie one user object contains a password object, a profile object, a collection of photo objects etc, each of those other objects is in another table